# RichFaces not loaded while opening application for the first time from some other Machine

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am doing my development work on Server. When I run application, it works fine with Richfaces, But when I open application from some other machine, Richfaces are not loaded on first(login page). And after login richfaces are loaded. I dont know what teh problem is.

Comment: Missing relevant facts. How we can help you? What is your expectation?

Comment: I think my question doesn't need the code to describe it. My question is very simple, that I have created an application on Server. When I run Application on Server it loads Richfaces there. But When I run it from another machine using IP of Server, It doesn't load richfaces on first page(Login Page) ie #{Login page is coded in using Richfaces, But I see it as a Simple HTML page. No Panel is shown}. After login, I am able to see the richfaces. Can you please tell me what are the relevant fact that you need to Answer my question?

Comment: JSF is server side technology. When you deploy your application on server it doesn't matter from which machine, using IP or server name you are accessing it. I don't think that problem is with proxy or cache on client side. If problem is in templates when different template is used for logged in and not logged in user, then it still not related on machine. Check logs, especially firebug on problematical machine.

Comment: Thanks Vasil for telling me that it is not Server problem. I am trying to find it. May it be because of the Filter Servlet, I am using for Login?